# Player VS player Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: vb.net, tic-tac-toe

This program is supposed to be a player VS player Tic-Tac-Toe game.  The computer then checks whether you've won, lost, or tied. The code does work, but I don't want it to work through hacking; I want it to be done the right way.

```
Sub Main()
'Initialise variables

Dim StrCoordinate(3, 3) As String
Dim BooGameOver As Boolean = False
Dim BooIsNextANaught As Boolean = False
Dim IntLoopCounterX As Integer = 0
Dim IntLoopCounterY As Integer = 0
Dim IntTempStorage As Integer = 1
Dim StrPlayAgain As String
Dim IntTempStorage2 As Integer = 0
Dim BooIsInputValid As Boolean = False


Do
    'Set all coordinates' contents to "-"
    For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
        For IntLoopCounterX = 0 To 2
            StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterX, IntLoopCounterY) = ("-")
        Next
    Next


    'Display Instructions
    Console.WriteLine("╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
    Console.WriteLine("║Welcome to this tic-tac-toe game!            ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║Please enter the coordinates as you are told ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║in order to place your X or 0 there.         ║")
    Console.WriteLine("╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Coordinates are as follows:")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╔═══╦═══╦═══╗")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "║1,1║2,1║3,1║")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╠═══╬═══╬═══╣")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "║1,2║2,2║3,2║")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╠═══╬═══╬═══╣")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "║1,3║2,3║3,3║")
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╚═══╩═══╩═══╝")
    Console.ReadKey()

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key once you have understood the instructions.")
    Console.Clear()


    Do
        'Display Empty Table
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╔═══╦═══╦═══╗")
        For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
            Console.Write(vbTab & "║ ")
            For IntLoopCounterX = 0 To 2
                Console.Write(StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterX, IntLoopCounterY) & " ║ ")
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
            If IntLoopCounterY = 2 Then
                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╚═══╩═══╩═══╝")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╠═══╬═══╬═══╣")
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine()

        'As player one or two for input
        If BooIsNextANaught = False Then
            Do
                'Ask player 1 for input
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
                Console.WriteLine(" PLAYER ONE")
                Console.WriteLine("═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════")
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter coordinate X, then enter. Then enter coordinate Y, then enter.")
                Console.WriteLine("Coordinates range from 1 to 3.")

                'Input coordinates for X
                Do
                    Console.Write("X (Column)> ")
                    IntTempStorage = Console.ReadLine
                    Console.Write("Y (Row)> ")
                    IntTempStorage2 = Console.ReadLine
                Loop Until IntTempStorage > 0 And IntTempStorage < 4 And IntTempStorage2 > 0 And IntTempStorage2 < 4

                'Check input
                Select Case StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1))
                    'Is input being used allready?
                    Case Is = ("X"), ("0")
                        BooIsInputValid = False
                        Console.Clear()
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed
                        Console.WriteLine("══════════════════")
                        Console.WriteLine("ALREADY USED SPACE")
                        Console.WriteLine("Please try again: ")
                        Console.WriteLine("══════════════════")
                        Console.WriteLine()
                        Console.WriteLine()
                        Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╔═══╦═══╦═══╗")
                        For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
                            Console.Write(vbTab & "║ ")
                            For IntLoopCounterX = 0 To 2
                                Console.Write(StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterX, IntLoopCounterY) & " ║ ")
                            Next
                            Console.WriteLine()
                            If IntLoopCounterY = 2 Then
                                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╚═══╩═══╩═══╝")
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╠═══╬═══╬═══╣")
                            End If
                        Next

                        Console.WriteLine()
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black

                    Case Is = ("-")
                        'Set StrCoordinate(input) with X
                        StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1)) = ("X")
                        BooIsInputValid = True
                        BooIsNextANaught = True

                        'check if winner:
                        For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
                            'check all rows:
                            If StrCoordinate(0, IntLoopCounterY) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(1, IntLoopCounterY) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(2, IntLoopCounterY) = ("X") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 1 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                                'check both diagonals:
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(0, 0) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(1, 1) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(2, 2) = ("X") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 1 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(0, 2) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(1, 1) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(3, 1) = ("X") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 1 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                                'check all columns
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 0) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 1) = ("X") And StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 2) = ("X") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 1 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                            End If
                        Next
                    Case Else
                        Console.WriteLine("It's Dead, Jim!")
                End Select

                Console.ResetColor()
            Loop Until BooIsInputValid = True

        Else
            Do
                'Ask player 2 for input
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
                Console.WriteLine(" PLAYER TWO")
                Console.WriteLine("═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════")
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter coordinate X, then enter. Then enter coordinate Y, then enter.")
                Console.WriteLine("Coordinates range from 1 to 3.")

                Do
                    Console.Write("X (Column)> ")
                    IntTempStorage = Console.ReadLine
                    Console.Write("Y (Row)> ")
                    IntTempStorage2 = Console.ReadLine
                Loop Until IntTempStorage > 0 And IntTempStorage < 4 And IntTempStorage2 > 0 And IntTempStorage2 < 4

                Select Case StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1))
                    Case Is = ("X"), ("0")
                        BooIsInputValid = False
                        Console.Clear()
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed
                        Console.WriteLine("══════════════════")
                        Console.WriteLine("ALREADY USED SPACE")
                        Console.WriteLine("Please try again: ")
                        Console.WriteLine("══════════════════")
                        Console.WriteLine()
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
                        Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╔═══╦═══╦═══╗")
                        For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
                            Console.Write(vbTab & "║ ")
                            For IntLoopCounterX = 0 To 2
                                Console.Write(StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterX, IntLoopCounterY) & " ║ ")
                            Next
                            Console.WriteLine()
                            If IntLoopCounterY = 2 Then
                                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╚═══╩═══╩═══╝")
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "╠═══╬═══╬═══╣")
                            End If
                        Next

                        Console.WriteLine()


                    Case Is = ("-")
                        StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1)) = ("0")
                        BooIsInputValid = True
                        BooIsNextANaught = False

                        'check if winner:
                        For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
                            'check all rows:
                            If StrCoordinate(0, IntLoopCounterY) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(1, IntLoopCounterY) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(2, IntLoopCounterY) = ("0") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 2 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                                'check both diagonals:
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(0, 0) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(1, 1) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(2, 2) = ("0") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 2 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(0, 2) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(1, 1) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(3, 1) = ("0") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 2 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                                'check all columns
                            ElseIf StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 0) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 1) = ("0") And StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterY, 2) = ("0") Then
                                BooGameOver = True
                                Console.WriteLine("══Player 2 wins══")
                                Console.ReadKey()
                            End If
                        Next

                    Case Else
                        Console.WriteLine("It's Dead, Jim!")
                End Select

                If Not StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1)) = ("-") Then

                Else
                    StrCoordinate((IntTempStorage - 1), (IntTempStorage2 - 1)) = ("0")
                    BooIsInputValid = True
                    BooIsNextANaught = False

                End If
                Console.ResetColor()
            Loop Until BooIsInputValid = True

        End If

        IntTempStorage = 0
        IntTempStorage2 = 0
        Console.Clear()

        If BooGameOver = False Then
            For IntLoopCounterY = 0 To 2
                For IntLoopCounterX = 0 To 2
                    If Not StrCoordinate(IntLoopCounterX, IntLoopCounterY) = ("-") Then
                        IntTempStorage2 = IntTempStorage2 + 1
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            If IntTempStorage2 = 9 Then
                BooGameOver = True
                Console.WriteLine("It's a draw")
            End If
            IntTempStorage = 0
            IntTempStorage2 = 0
        End If

    Loop Until BooGameOver = True
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? Y/N")

    StrPlayAgain = UCase(Console.ReadLine)
    Select Case StrPlayAgain
        Case Is = ("Y")
            BooGameOver = False
        Case Else
            BooGameOver = True
    End Select

Loop Until BooGameOver = True

REM End
Console.WriteLine()
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
Console.Write("EndOfProgram. ")
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue
Console.Write("Enter any key to close.")
Console.WriteLine()
Console.ReadKey()
Console.ResetColor()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a big bad block of monolithic code here, stuffed in a does-it-all `Main()` procedure that is *begging* to be broken down into smaller, more focused procedures and functions.

You need to first **identify concerns**:

- **Writing** to console
- **Reading** from console
- **Evaluating** game state

Writing to the console involves several distinct operations:

- Rendering the game title/instructions screen.
- Rendering the game screen (the 3x3 grid).
- Rendering the *game over* screen.

Reading from the console also involves several distinct operations:

- Displaying a message and waiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be pressed.
- Displaying a message and getting valid coordinates from the user.
- Displaying a message and getting a <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> answer from the user.

Create **classes** to *encapsulate* each concern, and write methods for each operation. As far as *best practices* are concerned, I'm biased with IoC and [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection), so my `Sub Main()` would probably look something like this:

```
Public Class Program

    Sub Main()

        Dim ConsoleReader As New ConsoleUserInputProvider()
        Dim Game As New TicTacToeGame(ConsoleReader)
        Game.Run()

    End Sub

End Class
```

The `Game` object encapsulates the game's *logic*; the `ConsoleUserInputProvider` exposes methods that `TicTacToeGame` uses to get the user's input. It implements some `IUserInputProvider` interface, which could just as well be implemented by some `WinFormsUserInputProvider` or `WpfUserInputProvider` if you wanted some fancypants GUI instead of just a console; the way you have your code, the concerns of *game logic* and *console input/output* are so tightly coupled it could very well be simpler to just rewrite the application from scratch to give it a new UI.

---

Your **naming** style is - I'll be gentle - from another era. [*Hungarian Notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is outdated and doesn't contribute in any way to make your code more readable: *drop those type prefixes!*

Comment: Small point in defence of the OP, I've personally mentored his computing class, and I can confirm that the teacher is from another era. Hungarian Notation is but one of his sins, and he has enforced his coding peculiarities onto the whole class.